# Inserting PDF into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf, layouts

I get this error, when I try to insert a pdf file into ArcMap Layout view. I have clicked on Insert - Object - create from file, browsed the geo pdf and pressed ok. I get this error:

> Failed to create object. Make sure the object is entered in the system registry <
>   I searched for this error and found this: 
>   http://support.esri.com/zh-cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27401
>   Where can I find the script blocking option in Nod32? defence temporary disable is not enough. Or the problem is not with the scripts running in background in that time?

Comment: Is Nod32 an anti-virus software?  Can you disable your anti-virus temporarily to test? Also, if you use Insert-Object-Pdf, I don't think ArcMap supports having full control over various layers in your pdf. I think it comes up as more of a static image.

Answer (score 1):

arcmap does not natively support pdf file format.
you can ...

1. convert your pdf to an image file format. (like jpg, png, tif, etc)
    I use [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) with the [pdf plugin](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) to do this.
2. purchase a third party product like [terrago](http://www.terragotech.com/products/geospatial-collaboration/terrago-publisher) publisher.
   EDIT:
   I just noticed that you are probably wanting to insert as an image.

   ## 1 or some derivative will do that.

   In fact file saveas in adobe will do that. (I have pro so not sure if it is in the free reader).
   [image: adobe save]

Comment: Free Adobe reader does not support that. It can convert to text files, Word, or Excel. However, GIMP (free) does support converting pdf to jpg, png, etc.

Comment: Well, it's a pdf with geographic datas, I mean multiple layers, points, polygons, etc. are in there. And I want to save that to be able for handle the different kind of datas.

Comment: @gregtom6 please edit your original question with more information. it is not clear what the final outcome that you want is.  1. you can insert a picture to the layout. 2. you can with terrago view the pdf as static image in arcmap with georeference (but that costs a bunch). 3. you can convert the pdf If it contains layers (I use pdf2cad) to vector data. which of the three are you after?